# Cassette + Web Forms: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode

Tags: webforms, cassette

I have a working ASP.NET Web Forms application and after installing the `Cassette.Aspnet` NuGet package I got the following error on first run:

> This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Cassette 2, you need to add the following line to your `web.config` file:

```xml
<cassette rewriteHtml="false" />
```

This will solve this issue, and also make the development web server happy.

---

That solution was found on the following [Github thread](https://github.com/andrewdavey/cassette/issues/80#issuecomment-17857648).