# 500.22 error after installing Cassette

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, cassette, asp.net-bundling

We want to start using Cassette in two products, which currently use asp.net bundling. One product is webforms and the other MVC. After adding the nuget package we get the following error (both use integrated pipeline)

> 500.22 - Internal Server Error (An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.)

I've replicated this by creating a new ASP.NET MVC v4 application and added the Cassette.aspnet nuget package.

I'm using Integrated mode so does this mean Cassette doesn't support integrated?

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281105/cassette-web-forms-this-operation-requires-iis-integrated-pipeline-mode) says to use

```
<cassette rewriteHtml="false" />
```

Does that mean that I cannot use this feature in an integrated mode application?

Alternatively i could try

```
 <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
 </system.webServer>
```

as in the following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370513/http-error-500-22-internal-server-error-an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected)

We just want to understand why this is occurring and if it has any implications for what features of cassette we can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting on this [google cassette newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cassette/3XmAHtzhlSw).

It seems the default nuget web.config.transform applies legacy classic sections which are no longer valid.

> In Web.config, under the  section, remove 
>   and . They are no longer used on IIS 7+ in integrated
>   mode; that is what the error is about.

I've created a [Github Issue](https://github.com/andrewdavey/cassette/issues/462) regarding this matter.